# Selecting same child from multiple li

Tags: jquery, css

I have built tables from ul and li list. I now want to toggle the class of the li "cells" but the same child from multiple divs in order to give the styling of highling a row, by changing the class of all the in line li.

1. On click of li child change class of same li child in all lists
2. On hover of li child change class of same li child in all lists

in affect highlighting a "row" on click and hover.

Please see below for basic outline for clarity.

**My Code**

```js
$("#cell").hover(function() {
  (".cd-features-list li").addClass("cellHover");
});

$("#cell").click(function() {
  (".cd-features-list li").addClass("cellClick");
});
```

```css
    .cellHover {
  background: #888;
  ) .cellClick {
    background: #111;
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-products-table">
  <div class="features">
    <div class="top-info">Models</div>
    <ul class="cd-features-list">
      <li>Programme Type</li>
      <li>Completion speed</li>
      <li>Visa Coverage</li>
      <li>Investment Type</li>
      <li>Min. Investment</li>
      <li>Family included</li>
      <li>Family entitlements</li>
      <li>PR time frame</li>
      <li>Citizenship time frame</li>
      <li>Annual min. stay</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- .features -->

  <div class="cd-products-wrapper">
    <ul class="cd-products-columns">
      <li class="product">
        <div class="top-info">
          <img src="/images/flags/portugal-flag.svg" alt="product image" height="100" width="230">
          <h3>Portugal</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="check"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- .top-info -->

        <ul class="cd-features-list">
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li class="rate"><span>5/5</span></li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- .product -->

      <li class="product">
        <div class="top-info">
          <img src="/images/flags/british-flag.svg" alt="product image" height="100" width="230">
          <h3>United Kingdom</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="check"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- .top-info -->

        <ul class="cd-features-list">
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li class="rate"><span>5/5</span></li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxxs</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>3 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- .product -->

      <li class="product">
        <div class="top-info">
          <img src="/images/flags/cypriot-flag.svg" alt="product image" height="100" width="230">
          <h3>Cyprus</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="check"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- .top-info -->

        <ul class="cd-features-list">
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li class="rate"><span>5/5</span></li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li> xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>3 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- .product -->
```

Comment: Please provide some executable code

Comment: What do you mean by "change class of same li child in all lists".  What is the condition for same li?

Comment: Hi thank you, I manage to highlight the whole ul, what i wanted is if li no.5 is hovered or clicked then the 5th li in all the ul are also changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this here  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84ksxg15/1/)

```js
$( ".cd-features-list > li" ).hover(
  function() { 
  var u=$(this).parent('ul');
   $(u).addClass("cellHover");
  }, function() {
   var u=$(this).parent('ul');
   $(u).removeClass("cellHover");
   
  }
);

$( ".cd-features-list li" ).click(function() { 
 var u=$(this).parent('ul');
   $(u).addClass("cellClick");
  }
);
```

```css
 .cellHover {
  background-color: #666666;
  }
  .cellClick {
    background: #111;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-products-table">
  <div class="features">
    <div class="top-info">Models</div>
    <ul class="cd-features-list">
      <li>Programme Type</li>
      <li>Completion speed</li>
      <li>Visa Coverage</li>
      <li>Investment Type</li>
      <li>Min. Investment</li>
      <li>Family included</li>
      <li>Family entitlements</li>
      <li>PR time frame</li>
      <li>Citizenship time frame</li>
      <li>Annual min. stay</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- .features -->

  <div class="cd-products-wrapper">
    <ul class="cd-products-columns">
      <li class="product">
        <div class="top-info">
          <img src="/images/flags/portugal-flag.svg" alt="product image" height="100" width="230">
          <h3>Portugal</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="check"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- .top-info -->

        <ul class="cd-features-list">
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li class="rate"><span>5/5</span></li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- .product -->

      <li class="product">
        <div class="top-info">
          <img src="/images/flags/british-flag.svg" alt="product image" height="100" width="230">
          <h3>United Kingdom</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="check"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- .top-info -->

        <ul class="cd-features-list">
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li class="rate"><span>5/5</span></li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxxs</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>3 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- .product -->

      <li class="product">
        <div class="top-info">
          <img src="/images/flags/cypriot-flag.svg" alt="product image" height="100" width="230">
          <h3>Cyprus</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="check"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- .top-info -->

        <ul class="cd-features-list">
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li class="rate"><span>5/5</span></li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li> xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>3 xxxxxxx</li>
          <li>1 xxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I manage to highlight the whole ul, what i wanted is if li no.5 is hovered or clicked then the 5th li in all the ul are also changed.

Comment: Oh thats it just learnt how you did that so thank you sir! looks great!

Answer (score 0):

In hover and click function you can use `this` to get the current element. Then using `parent("ul")`, you can select the parent element and using that you can find all the `"li"` and you can do whatever you want with those element.

```
$( "li" ).hover(function() { 
        $(this).parent('ul').find("li").addClass("cellHover");
  }, function() {
        $(this).parent('ul').find("li").removeClass("cellHover");
  }
);

$( "li" ).click(function() { 
 $(this).parent('ul').find("li").addClass("cellClick");
  }
);
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/84ksxg15/1/)

Comment: Hi thank you, I manage to highlight the whole ul, what i wanted is if li no.5 is hovered or clicked then the 5th li in all the ul are also changed.